# Splunk count ORA error group by

Tags: splunk

I am new to Splunk, I want to implement below however stuck there:
I could get results as below format:

```
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
ORA-XXXXX: ....
```

What I want is to see the count value for each ORA error. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to [create a field extraction](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.1/Knowledge/ExtractfieldsinteractivelywithIFX). A regular expression for your field might look like this `^ORA-\d+`. When you got the field you can simply group and count by it:

```
* | stats count by <your-new-field>
```